# Regex dismatch repeat special character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm doing a regex to check a slug.
Actually my regex is : `/^[^-][a-z\-].*[^-]+$/`

here's what I'm checking right now :

`my-awesome-project` => valid

`-my-awesome-project` => invalid

`my-awesome-project-` => invalid

Now what I want is to check if the dash is repeating or not :

`my-awesome-project` => should be valid

`my-awesome--project` => should not be valid

`my----awesome-project` => should not be valid

Can I do that with a regex ?

Thank you,

Comment: A small point: if a hypen is at the beginning or end of character class (e.g., `[a-z-]` or `[-a-z]`), it does not need to be escaped (as Ruby recognizes that it cannot signify a range in such cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this regexp should work:

```
/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$/
```

What this does: `^[a-z]+` matches if the string begins with at least on character. After that there may be `(-[a-z]+)*$` zero or more occurances of a dash followed by again at least one character.

See on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/NjRxgJTlLf).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the string is valid unless it:

- contains a character other than a lower-case letter or hyphen,
- begins with a hyphen,
- ends with a hyphen, or
- contains two (or more) hyphens in a row.

If that's the case, it's easiest to check if it invalid:

```
R = /
    [^a-z-] # match one character other than a lower-case letter or hyphen
    |       # or
    ^-      # match a hyphen as the first character
    |       # or
    -$      # match a hyphen as the last character
    |       # or
    --      # match two hypens
    /x    

def valid?(str)
  str !~ R
end

valid? 'my-awesome-project'    #=> true 
valid? '-my-awesome-project'   #=> false 
valid? 'my-awesome-project-'   #=> false 
valid? 'my-awesome--project'   #=> false 
valid? 'my----awesome-project' #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Below regex may be helpful.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*
```